# Mount Windows network drive in Docker container (Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, docker, dockerfile, network-drive

I am trying to mount Windows shared drive into Linux. I also want it to be in the docker container, so would like to add few commands in Dockerfile. (Then, it will mount whenever container is created)

1. Is there anyway without using 3rd party libraries like CIFS?
2. If #1 is not possible, should I do `RUN mkdif -p simpliciti` then, `mount -t cifs......`

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04, to connect to a Windows Network from Linux you have have to open `nautilus` (the Linux "Files Explorer"), click `Other Locations`, then on `connect to Server` enter the address of the Windows network.

By clicking on the `?` button, it shows a list of possible ways of connecting.

For Windows, it's likely to be samba (`smb://etc`).

And to mount it on a docker container, you would mount it normally:

```
docker run -it -v /path/on/linux/:/path/on_container DOCKER_IMAGE_HERE /bin/bash
```

Below we have an Image showing what I described here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use cifs.

Instead of mounting you can install and use `smbclient` inside your image, but mounting a remote share as a volume and mapping it to docker would be easier to use.